# Clear all personal data in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, privacy, personal-data

In Windows XP, there was an option to clean all stored user data, passwords, visited websites, MRUs, searches and so on in one swift. This option appears to have disappeared in Windows 7.

How do I clean *all* personal data on a Windows-7 machine? Do I need a third party program? Or is the botton to rid them just hidden for me to see?

(Please note that this is not a duplicate since the similar questions were asking about only specific subsets of the personal data.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try [Ccleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner). It will do all of this and more for you in a jiffy. And if you are not satisfied by the defaults, you can add/remove custom files and folders from the cleaning process. Here you can take a look at all its [features](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/features)

Comment: Ccleaner also now has an option to wipe free space, make sure you enable that too.

Also if I was cleaning the computer in order to give it to someone else/sell it etc I would also delete the user accounts and clean the free space also.